# dojo select set maximum width

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

i have a problem with the width of my dojo select. The option of the select widget are filled by an ajax call. A few of the labels are very long and the width of the select widget grows with the large of the label. Is there a way to set the maximum width of the select widget? So that the width don't grow over 180px? PS: I implement the widget by programmatically  way like

```
new Select({
    name: "select2"
}).placeAt(win.body())
```

Edit: Here for example http://jsfiddle.net/5r3gR/3/ when i select the "VeryVeryVeryLongLabel" the width of the select dijit changes but it should stay at the width.

Comment: Can you add whatever theme you are using to your fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the claro theme with the added rule of...

```
.dijitSelectLabel {
    text-align:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100px;
}
```

Which makes the width of the textbox static at 100px. The dropdown options will still expand out to the biggest width of your option

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uTtd6/2/)

To style different selects with different widths make the following changes

**Css**

```
.bigSelect .dijitSelectLabel {
    text-align:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:200px;
}

.smallSelect .dijitSelectLabel {
    text-align:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100px;
}
```

**Code**

```
var big = new Select({
    store: os,
    class: "bigSelect"
}, "target");

var small = new Select({
    store: os,
    class: "smallSelect"
}, "target");
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VjLG2/)

Comment: Nice answer.  I'd add a call to `startup()` - a required part of the dijit lifecycle.

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uTtd6/1/

Comment: Oh thanks it works :). Is there a way to add the style programmaticaly to the dijit.select.label? I have a few of select widgets and all of them have a specific width.

Comment: Edited to have Selects have different widths