# Dojo filtering widget data overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I'm working on dojo 1.6 and I use a dijit.form.Select widget. 
The problem I'm facing now is when I select a long text from the dropdown, it goes beyond the width of the widget. I want the string to be enclosed in the width allotted to the widget. I tried using the overflow: hidden attribute but it is not working. Please help. Here is the code segment which I'm working on.

```
        this.dapNAME = new dijit.form.Select({

            name            : "NAME",
            placeHolder     : 'Enter Name',
            maxHeight       : -1,
            style           : {width: '265px'}
        }, this.dapNAME);
```

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790815/how-do-i-set-the-width-of-dijit-form-select),  which should help you in solving you issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken the answer from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790815/how-do-i-set-the-width-of-dijit-form-select)

There is another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24640101/dojo-select-set-maximum-width) which might help too.

you need to style your css. Remember to replace the **tundra** style with whatever style ( claro, nihilo, etc..) you have chosen for your site.

```
.tundra .dijitSelect .dijitButtonText {
    text-align: left;
}

.tundra .dijitSelectLabel {
    width: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This is not what he/she wants as I understand. Your answer does not change the width of the select options.

Comment: @dbd Can you explain your comments please?. I think the user wants that the text when selected and displayed should not go beyond the allotted width of the widget.